# How to get MenuItem clicked events from TreeView ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I am inserting TreeViewItems into a TreeView control and setting the style for each at the time of insertion. I am assigning different styles (predefined in XAML), depending on the type of node (TreeViewItem) I want to insert. Some of the styles include a ContextMenu.

My problem is that I am unable to use Click="MyHandler" on the MenuItems; I get an error "root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file." and apparently none of the elements within the Style block are root elements.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="Terrain" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Canvas Background="{DynamicResource Terrain_icon}" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                 <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu> 
                       <MenuItem Header="Edit..." Click="MyHandler"/> <!-- Error -->
                       <MenuItem Header="Add..."/>
                       <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                    </ContextMenu> 
                 </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
             </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

C#:

```
private void InsertTerrainNode(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Add the new item under the first-level TreeViewItem
   TreeViewItem tvi = myTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myTree.Items[0]) as TreeViewItem;
   TreeViewItem newTerrainNode = new TreeViewItem();
   newTerrainNode.Header = "Terrain";
   newTerrainNode.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("Terrain");
   tvi.Items.Insert(0,newTerrainNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use commands, create a class derived from ICommand, declare in the class that have access to user controles and  is accessible in your xaml and bind button with that command. see [here](http://blogs.conchango.com/richardgriffin/archive/2007/02/23/WPF-Commands-a-scenic-tour-part-I.aspx) for detailes

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add an event handler for the `MenuItem.Click` event to the `TreeViewItem` as you create it.

```
private void InsertTerrainNode(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add the new item under the first-level TreeViewItem
    TreeViewItem tvi = myTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myTree.Items[0]) as TreeViewItem;
    TreeViewItem newTerrainNode = new TreeViewItem();
    newTerrainNode.Header = "Terrain";
    newTerrainNode.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("Terrain");
    newTerrainNode.AddHandler(MenuItem.Click, OnTreeItemContextMenuClicked);
    tvi.Items.Insert(0,newTerrainNode);
}

private void OnTreeItemContextMenuClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the ContextMenu item click here
    // e.OriginalSource can be used to get the ContextMenu item clicked if needed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, this has got me on the right track I think. I now have

C#:
    newTerrainNode.ContextMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnTreeItemContextMenuClicked));

However, I get a runtime error:

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TreeTest2.MainWindow.InsertTerrainNode(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What line in your event handler is throwing the exception?

Comment: When the event handler is added - 

newTerrainNode.AddHandler(MenuItem.Click, OnTreeItemContextMenuClicked);

I thought it may be because the TreeViewItem hadn't been inserted into the tree at that point, but I get the same error (for the same line of code) if I add the handler after tvi.Items.Insert(0,newTerrainMode);

Comment: It's probably because newTerrainNode.ContextMenu is null. I think it should work if you call AddHandler() off of newTerrainNode.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried initially as per your code. No errors, but the OnTreeContextMenuClicked handler isn't fired when a context menu item is clicked.